# Angular 4 - Get routeparms as @input

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

If I have component that is bound to a specific route (Let say OrdersListComponent is bound to /orders/:userId).

If I understand correctly, in order to recive the userId within the component I need to use this.route.snapshot.params.userId in constructor.
whats badgering me is the case when I want to use this component in another component, which in this case I will recive it in the @input() binding.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: UIRouter supports mapping route parameters to inputs. https://ui-router.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Inject the router service in your component. Then pass the reference to the routerparams, either from the snapshot as a js object or from the currentRoute itself as an observable